# AWS policy for step functions: some actions, resources, or conditions do not provide permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions

I am editing a policy document to allow Lambda executing the step function. A statement below, although granting the right permissions, causes the warning to appear. I need advice if this is a "false positive" warning, or I am actually misconfiguring a policy document.

Statement that causes the warning:

```json
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "states:SendTaskSuccess",
        "states:SendTaskFailure"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:stateMachine:sample-waiting-step-machine"
    }
```

Warning text:

```
This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions 
that do not provide permissions. To grant access, policies 
must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition. 
For details, choose Show remaining.
```

Once I tick "show remaining services", the following warning shows up in the table too:

[image: warning screenshot]

All advices are appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awsstepfunctions.html is the best doc for figuring out the minutia of IAM permissions and the resources to which they apply.  Looking at the SendTaskSuccess and SendTaskFailure, it doesn't appear to apply to a task itself.  In fact there's no resource listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actions `states:SendTaskSuccess`, `states:SendTaskFailure` only support the all resources wildcard('*'). From the IAM policy editor, you can verify this:-

[image]

From the AWS docs also if you see the [action table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awsstepfunctions.html) for the AWS Step Functions for actions `SendTaskFailure` and `SendTaskSuccess`, the Resource types column is empty. And the docs state:

> The **Resource types** column indicates whether the action supports resource-level permissions. If the column is empty, then the action does not support resource-level permissions and you must specify all resources ("*") in your policy

I hope this helps.