# Not able to call sendTaskSuccess from lamda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions

I have a lamda function from which I want to update status for step function using the SFN sdk method sendTaskSuccessCommand. 
Here is the code that I am using

```
import { SFNClient, SendTaskSuccessCommand, SendTaskFailureCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sfn";
....
const client = new SFNClient({'region': 'us-east-1'});
const command = new SendTaskSuccessCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
```

When I test this lamda with a valid task token, I get following error.

```
error User: <my user arn>:assumed-role/<my lamda role arn> is not authorized to perform: states:SendTaskSuccess on resource: <my step function arn> because no identity-based policy allows the states:SendTaskSuccess action
```

To fix this error, I added following permission to my lamda role

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "states:SendTaskFailure",
        "states:SendTaskSuccess"
      ],
      "Resource": "resource arn"
}
```

But I still get the same error. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060358/aws-policy-for-step-functions-some-actions-resources-or-conditions-do-not-pro.  The accepted answer says that only the `"*"` wildcard resource is accepted for `SendTaskSuccess`